# ReactDom render multiple elements spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

Let me start by saying I am working on my first webpart and learning react spfx. I am trying to render multiple elements using ReactDom.render. How do I render both the elements on the same .ts file? This is a multiscreen webpart which I have realized has only one .ts file running at the initiation. 
    `//ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);---This is for spfxcontext and oninit`
    `ReactDom.render(React.createElement(App), this.domElement);---This is for rendering the Reactrouter headers`
How do I declare both in the .ts file? When I use one of them, my header is appearing but spfxcontext and context from init and props are not loading. And when I just use other one, only my list data is populating and my component in app is not loading.
I want both of them to be shown when the webpart loads.

Below is the full code:

```
export default class MultiScreenWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IReactGetItemsWebPartProps> {
public onInit(): Promise < void> {
console.log("init is running");
return super.onInit().then(_ => {
  sp.setup( this.context);
});
  }
  public render(): void {
console.log("render is running");
const element: React.ReactElement<IReactGetItemsProps> = React.createElement(
  ReactGetItems,
  {
    description: this.properties.description,
    context: this.context
  }
);
//ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
ReactDom.render(React.createElement(App), this.domElement);
```

}

Here is my webpart structure.[Link to my github proj](https://github.com/schittuluri1/react-multiscreen-webpart/tree/master/src/webparts/multiScreenWebPart/components). I have the .ts files of no use as they are not rendering when webpart is loading. Only the MultiscreenWebPart.ts is loading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`MultiScreenWebPart` is your WebPart class which typically will render a single ReactJS component, but then that component can `Render` whatever you need.  You currently have `ReactGetItems` as your primary component, and within that component class you are already rendering other React components such as `Tabs`, `PeoplePicker` and `PrimaryButton`.

Inside that `ReactGetItems`, at the top if you `import { Header } from './Header'` then you can use your custom `<Header>` component in the `Render` just like you are using other imported React components.  Likewise for your `Home`, `Product` etc. components.

Comment: Thanks @willman
I am not trying to import Header into ReactGetitems, I am trying to load App through ReactDom.render(React.createElement(App), this.domElement); which renders the header and other routes work fine.<br> If I wanted to load context, and also have the routes working that is when I am having issue.

Comment: Then you need import `App` into your ` MultiScreenWebPart` class and change the `render` method of ` MultiScreenWebPart` to load `app` instead of `reactgetitems`.